# How do I make the html source formatting

Tags: php, html, formatting

**How do I make the html source formatting in php**

Sample:

```
<?
    ob_start();

    $mixed_output = 
    "<div><div>2.</div><div>
          <div>4.</div>
             <div>4.</div>
    </div>  <div>2.</div>
      <div>2.</div>
    </div>";

    echo format_mixed_output($mixed_output);
?>
```

i want to be this:

```
<html>
    <div>
      <div>2.</div>
        <div>
          <div>4.</div>
          <div>4.</div>
        </div>
      <div>2.</div>
      <div>2.</div>
    </div>
</html>
```

i can't find source in net, please help me...

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768215/php-pretty-print-html-not-tidy

Comment: thenks, but not run,  http://www.coderun.com/ide/?w=d35PTnzNW0-Pwk2Fnry6GA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use "[Tidy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php)".

Example: http://www.php.net/manual/en/tidy.examples.basic.php

Your example would be something like this:

```
<?php
    $mixed_output = 
"<div><div>2.</div><div>
      <div>4.</div>
         <div>4.</div>
</div>  <div>2.</div>
  <div>2.</div>
</div>";

$config = array(
            'indent'         => true,
            'output-xml'     => true,
            'input-xml'     => true,
            'wrap'         => '1000');

$tidy = new tidy();
$tidy->parseString($mixed_output, $config, 'utf8');
$tidy->cleanRepair();
echo tidy_get_output($tidy);
?>
```

Comment: same output http://www.coderun.com/ide/?w=d35PTnzNW0-Pwk2Fnry6GA am I doing wrong i??