# Beautify HTML stored in a string on PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a string in variable `$html` that contains minified HTMl code, all in one line, like:

```
$html = '<body><div><p>hello</p><div></body>';
```

How do I beautify/pretty print the HTML so that my variable becomes like:

```
 $html = '<body>
             <div>
               <p>hello</p>
             <div>
          </body>';
```

I know the [tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) extension is a possibility, but how can this be done without an extension.

EDIT: **PLEASE read the question. I am not asking how to beautify HTML code via some external site. I am asking how to do it in PHP, specifically targeting the string variable.**

Comment: I generally paste it into Jsfiddle and hit Tidy button.

Comment: @AycanYaşıt Sure, we all have our ways, but I am asking how to do this using PHP, and not jsfiddle. :)

Comment: So you search for something like this, right? http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php

Comment: this might help if you don't want to use `tidy` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768215/php-pretty-print-html-not-tidy

Comment: You want  beatified output or not??

Comment: Then you should use  `tidy`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using `DomDocument` we load the html passing the `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED` flag
 which will prevent the `loadHTML` method to add the extra `html` wrapper.

We save as XML to get the nice indentation, while passing the `$dom->documentElement` parameter to prevent the `XML` header.

```
$html = '<body><div><p>hello</p><div></body>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->loadHTML($html,LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);
$dom->formatOutput = true;


print $dom->saveXML($dom->documentElement);
```

This will output

```
<body>
  <div>
    <p>hello</p>
    <div/>
  </div>
</body>
```

Notice that the `HTML` was fixed for you as the second `div` should have been a closing tag, I assume.

If we pass the proper `HTML` as the input string, the output will be as you require

```
$html = '<body><div><p>hello</p></div></body>';

<body>
  <div>
    <p>hello</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I ended up going with the following approach: http://pastebin.com/Q94UbgSW Which is very similar to yours. Does yours do anything different (or better for that matter)?

Comment: I just checked the output of your function and I see it has the `DOCTYPE` declaration and the `html` tag wrapper. Also no indentation.

Comment: If your solution works for you, then use it :) It's all about what ultimately works for **you**

Comment: I know but what I am asking is, does your approach work better generally? I am scrapping various HTML from sites, storing it in the variable, and tidying it up with this function. Will yours work better in terms of compatibility with different type of HTML code?

Comment: not really, the only difference between my approach and yours is what I pointed out  above, the lack of indentation, extra `DOCTYPE` and `html`. If you pass incorrect `html` it will still get fixed for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation!

Comment: This is genius, very nice solution!

Comment: If you've to deal with messy code that is not validating, then this way is a limited option. While you get hints about faults in the code, display might break and you've to work from top to bottom to solve the issues and to get shown the whole page.
For validating it's good but for partial work this is not an option.

Answer (score 4):

I've used `DOMDocument` but it seems that it is very sensitive to broken html and html errors.

Anyhow, `DOMDocument` require `dom extension` so I've used [tidy php extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/tidy.examples.basic.php) as it works perfect to me - it fix html errors and prettify html as well.

Use code from example:

```
$config = array(
       'indent'         => true,
       'output-xhtml'   => true,
       'wrap'           => 200);

 // Tidy
$tidy = new \tidy;
$tidy->parseString($html, $config, 'utf8');
$tidy->cleanRepair();

// Output
echo $tidy;
```

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not aware of any pre-built things to do that (most parsers provide functionality to minify HTML, not prettify it), it shouldn't be too hard to do yourself:

1. Parse the HTML. `DOMDocument` might be a good idea for that.
2. Recurse through the document. For each element...

   1. Output the opening tag - you will need to loop through attributes too
   2. If it contains no child elements (but possibly child text), output its `textContent`
      Otherwise, recurse into the element, outputting each child node, be it text or element. Indent appropriately based on number of recursion levels.
   3. Output the closing tag.

And... that's it. Shouldn't be too difficult :)