# How to print formatted html using Twig?

Tags: html, twig

I pass into twig template variable that contains html code. When I print it I get something like that:

```
<div class="links"> <span class="logo"></span> <a href="/">homepage</a> <a href="/page_1">page 1</a> <a href="/page_2">page 2</a> <a href="/page_3">page 3</a> </div>
```

How do i make the code look more readable? Like this:

```
 <div class="links">
    <span class="logo"></span>
    <a href="/">homepage</a>
    <a href="/page_1">page 1</a>
    <a href="/page_2">page 2</a>
    <a href="/page_3">page 3</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display the `html`as is for a code snippet I'd suggest you just wrap `<pre>` around it.

```html
<pre>{{ html }}</pre>
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/0gsxde)

If you just want to preserve newlines and tabbing you could wrap the var with div and set the white-space to `pre`

```html
<style>
    div.pre {
        white-space: pre;
    }
</style>
<div class="pre">{{ html }}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The source HTML is displayed exactly as you pass it in. One way I can think of to fix this specific issue is by using a solution like https://stackoverflow.com/a/34556900/4646470 to format the HTML and create a Twig filter/function [1](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/advanced.html) to handle it in Twig templates.

Comment: This is incorrect as seen [here](https://www.darkbee.be/stack/html.php)

Answer (score -2):

I am giving the sample example solution to your questions. I hope it helps you.

```html
{{ title }} {{ entity_print_css }} {{ content }}
```

Sample node--article--pdf.html.twig

```html
{{ content.field_name }} {{ content.body }} {{ label }} {{ content.field_name.0.value }}
```

Comment: Not sure how this relates to the question?